# Using SDL2 for Capturing Key strokes

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Have 2 questions related to using SDL2.

1. I want to capture all the keyboard inputs in my C++ app. The app is a COM dll that will run in the background and will capture all the inputs. So this app doesn't have a window, in this case is it possible to capture keyboard inputs? If yes, how?

I have seen examples for SDL2 where they 1st create a SDL window and then capture keyboard inputs. But i don't want that. What i want is my app to be able to capture all keyboard inputs by its own.

1. If i create my own window using MFC, is it possible to attach that to SDL2 and have it capture all keyboard inputs when my window is in focus. Again i don't want to create a SDL Window.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GetAsyncKeyState it's simple and fast,
this code shows you how to use it.

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState('Q')){//if Q key has been clicked
   //Do something
}
```

and here is list of all key codes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am not looking to use any Windows function calls. I want to use SDL for this purpose, so that the piece of code will multi-platform compatible.

Comment: check out this http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlgetkeystate.html

Comment: This also only works if i do a "SDL_CreateWindow". i.e., it will pop open a SDL window. Which i don't want to do.

Comment: SDL uses its own program entry point while MFC apps use the standard WinMain. I think there is no other way around that than to modify the SDL sources and re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

> So this app doesn't have a window, in this case is it possible to capture keyboard inputs?

Not with SDL.

> If i create my own window using MFC, is it possible to attach that to SDL2 and have it capture all keyboard inputs when my window is in focus.

It [sounds](https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=29637#29637) like you might have some luck with [`SDL_CreateWindowFrom()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindowFrom).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to have an window with the SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN flag. That way i would assume you could get he input with the sdl functions without having an window pop.

Not sure if this is what you want, but i hope it helps.